spring boot mongo db Exception opening socket caused by: No route to host
I have a spring boot app version 3.3.5 with “spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb” dependency.
When it tries to connect to mongo db (running on docker 0.0.0.0:27018:27017) I get the following error:
2024-11-07T14:34:07.061+01:00  INFO 16657 --- [middleware] [  restartedMain] org.mongodb.driver.client                : MongoClient with metadata {"driver": {"name": "mongo-java-driver|sync|spring-boot", "version": "5.0.1"}, "os": {"type": "Darwin", "name": "Mac OS X", "architecture": "aarch64", "version": "15.0.1"}, "platform": "Java/Oracle Corporation/23.0.1+11-39"} created with settings MongoClientSettings{readPreference=primary, writeConcern=WriteConcern{w=null, wTimeout=null ms, journal=null}, retryWrites=true, retryReads=true, readConcern=ReadConcern{level=null}, credential=null, transportSettings=null, commandListeners=[io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.mongodb.MongoMetricsCommandListener@265cb4df], codecRegistry=ProvidersCodecRegistry{codecProviders=[ValueCodecProvider{}, BsonValueCodecProvider{}, DBRefCodecProvider{}, DBObjectCodecProvider{}, DocumentCodecProvider{}, CollectionCodecProvider{}, IterableCodecProvider{}, MapCodecProvider{}, GeoJsonCodecProvider{}, GridFSFileCodecProvider{}, Jsr310CodecProvider{}, JsonObjectCodecProvider{}, BsonCodecProvider{}, EnumCodecProvider{}, com.mongodb.client.model.mql.ExpressionCodecProvider@4f9bccaf, com.mongodb.Jep395RecordCodecProvider@8d2b261, com.mongodb.KotlinCodecProvider@6d8951c9]}, loggerSettings=LoggerSettings{maxDocumentLength=1000}, clusterSettings={hosts=[10.11.11.11:27018], srvServiceName=mongodb, mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, requiredReplicaSetName='null', serverSelector='null', clusterListeners='[]', serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', localThreshold='15 ms'}, socketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=0, receiveBufferSize=0, proxySettings=ProxySettings{host=null, port=null, username=null, password=null}}, heartbeatSocketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=10000, receiveBufferSize=0, proxySettings=ProxySettings{host=null, port=null, username=null, password=null}}, connectionPoolSettings=ConnectionPoolSettings{maxSize=100, minSize=0, maxWaitTimeMS=120000, maxConnectionLifeTimeMS=0, maxConnectionIdleTimeMS=0, maintenanceInitialDelayMS=0, maintenanceFrequencyMS=60000, connectionPoolListeners=[io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.mongodb.MongoMetricsConnectionPoolListener@11ae6387], maxConnecting=2}, serverSettings=ServerSettings{heartbeatFrequencyMS=10000, minHeartbeatFrequencyMS=500, serverListeners='[]', serverMonitorListeners='[]'}, sslSettings=SslSettings{enabled=false, invalidHostNameAllowed=false, context=null}, applicationName='null', compressorList=[], uuidRepresentation=JAVA_LEGACY, serverApi=null, autoEncryptionSettings=null, dnsClient=null, inetAddressResolver=null, contextProvider=null}
2024-11-07T14:34:07.078+01:00  INFO 16657 --- [middleware] [01.11.11:27018] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 10.11.11.11:27018

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.lambda$open$0(SocketStream.java:86) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:86) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:201) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:193) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:153) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1575) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:589) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:583) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:760) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:76) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:105) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:80) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    ... 4 common frames omitted

The problem is that it sometimes works and sometimes not.
P.S. Connection with MongoDB compass works always.
Any ideas? Any help?
Thank you

can you paste docker compose file(if exists) and application.properties file

"No route to host" usually means the local firewall on the server blocks incoming connections from remote machine. But I am not familiar neither with Docker nor with Java.

Problem solved.
access right in Mac OS. the problem was a misleading question whether IntelliJ can discover devices in local network or not.
Wasn't a question whether IntelliJ is allowed to access local network.
